# how to display Image in ImageView?

Tags: iphone, imageview

I am new to programming and developing my first application, but I want to know that how can I display image to imageView.

Answer (score 5):

**Programmatically :**

From http://www.iphoneexamples.com/:

```
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 109.0f);
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect]; 
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
myImage.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance 
[self.view addSubview:myImage]; 
[myImage release];
```

Where myImage.png is an png format image which you will import to your resources folder.

**Using Nib(Xib File):**

- Open your.xib file.
- Go to Tools -> Library.
- Drag and drop one UIImageView on your .xib.
- Open Attribute Inspector of the ImageView(Press Cmd + 1).
- You'll get one Image property. Set the image you want from your Resource folder using the drop-down list.
- There you got it. :-)

Comment: but I am new and I asked a friend, he said that using xib is not good practice when you are new to iphone programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
// First way     
myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];  

// Second way  
NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/myImage.png"];
myImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath];
```

Check out **UIImageView** class reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try it using:

```
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Read http://www.iphoneexamples.com/

```
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 109.0f);
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
myImage.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance
[self.view addSubview:myImage];
[myImage release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
```

(If you have created imageView from IB and have outlet-ed it then ignore First Line)