# How do I create an iPhone app with background and rotating images?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am making the transition to iPhone programming and found [how to display Image in ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409313/how-to-display-image-in-imageview) to answer some of my questions, but did not specify a couple of basics, namely what kind of project(s) can display an image, and where in the project the code can be put. I created an empty project and am getting errors for the last two lines of:

```
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 109.0f);
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect]; 
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
myImage.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance 
[self.view addSubview:myImage]; 
[myImage release];
```

If I am going to display a clock face, eventually one with rotating hands but for now the goal is to display the face itself, can I do it with a basic project, or do I need to start over with another project, and where should I be placing the sample code? http://www.iphoneexamples.com/ has AFAICT some excellent examples, but they seem to assume you know where to put the code in question, and that you have chosen whatever is the most appropriate project.

So, let's say I am not trying to animate the clock hands immediately, and for now I want my (PNG) clock face to show, optionally well-positioned on the screen. What kind of project do I start with, where do I put the code to display the image, and what code should I be using to display the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Interface Builder or your Storyboard, if you started an empty project you probably don't have any of these, I'd recommend you to start with a Single View project, then on Interface Builder or the Storyboard, from the Library drag an Image View (also called UIImageView) and place it on your canvas, using the properties bar on the right you can set the image just like in the following image

[image]

That way you get to display an image on a view, resize the view properly to fit your image dimesions and repeat for every other image you want to add.

For what you are asking my guess is that you are pretty new to iOS Development, I can recommend you [Beginning iOS 6 Development: Exploring the iOS SDK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ACC69HO)

Comment: Thank you; you've just named my next Safari Bookshelf item.

Comment: How did you get to the exact GUI state shown in your response? I've moved around through the UI, opened up the storyboard, and not seen the icons at the top of your screen, nor anything labelled "Image View". How can I get to your display of "Image View"?

Comment: place an Image View on your main View and then select it :)

Comment: +1 for book recommendation, I got the book on the weekend and it's brilliant :)