# Streaming video frames from server with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am sending frames of a video in form of JPEG images to my server on RMTP stream.  At server side, I want to connect the stream (ip + port) to ffmpeg so that it can grab images from stream and create a video stream from them.

Actually my server is listening on an IP and port for incoming frames.  This part is done.  Where I am stuck is that how to convert these frames to a video stream using ffmpeg.  Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this?  I know `image2pipe` is what I should go with but I have not found its syntax and documentation on Google.

Comment: What output format do you want? What is the input to ffmpeg: RTMP or a pipe? ffmpeg can do either.

Comment: At client end that is iPhone app, I will send images in form of images jpeg format. I am not sure if I will use pipe or RTMP. This is what I want to discuss with you guys. Also I want to stream the video directly to the viewers in form of RTMP stream.

Answer (score 2):

**At the server side**, you can invoke the cmd-line line application `ffmpeg` to do the heavy lifting for you and [stream the data](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide).

**At the client side**, there are 2 approaches I want to discuss:

### **Approach 1**: use `ffplay` on the iPhone to connect to the server and display the video stream.

**Pros**: this is the easiest and fastest solution!

[FFmpeg was ported to the iPhone](https://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg4iphone/) by some people a long time ago, so you can just invoke `ffplay` from the iPhone, tell it to connect to the server and the job is done! Check [Streaming a simple RTP audio stream from FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#StreamingasimpleRTPaudiostreamfromFFmpeg) for a quick example.

**Cons**: It seems that [there are legal issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17622379/176769) [involved on this matter](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1229), so some people do not recommend distributing your app with FFmpeg.

### **Approach 2**: write an application similar to `ffplay` for the iPhone.

**Pros**: You can have custom encode/decode procedures to protect the data being broadcasted and make everyone else in the world use your player to watch the stream.

If you are streaming a real JPEG (with headers and all, just like a regular JPEG file), the first thing you need is use a [networking library](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to allow your application to connect to server and retrieve the data.

I suggest that for every new connection your server receives, it sends a custom header (a few bytes) informing the client about the size of each frame that is being sent (so the client knows the size of each frame).

After that, the app will need to use another library to interpret the incoming data as a JPEG frame/file. I can think of OpenCV right now, but I'm sure you can find smaller libraries. Maybe iOS offers a framework for this, but I really don't know.

Once your application has access to all the useful information that each frame carries (i.e., image dimension and pixels) your app will create an [`UIImage`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) [with this information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4545237/176769) for every frame that arrives from the network, to be able to [display them on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6409313/176769).

**Cons**: You will have to create an application from scratch and probably learn a few new APIs on the way.

Comment: Hi karlphilllip, I don't want to use ffmpeg on iPhone. My idea was that iPhone will just send video frames in form of jpeg images to server and server will do rest of the things like encoding it into video and then streaming it.

Comment: Then **Approach 2** is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is 2 methods:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://localhost/etc" out.flv
```

or

```
rtmpdump -v -r rtmp://localhost/etc | ffmpeg -i - out.flv
```

Comment: Hi Alex I don't want flv file, I want to stream the data directly to output stream for viewers

Comment: In that case why not replace ffmpeg by ffplay ?